# significance values in corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I've found this plot on [corrplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) [image: corrplot]:

What do I see there? The correlations are coloured according to {-1,1} and significance values are applied, represented by a cross.
What do these crosses tell? Are they located in entries which violate the significance value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation carefully it says:

> Combining correlogram with the significance test
>       `res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = .95)`
>       `res2 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = .99)`
>       ## specialized the insignificant value according to the significant level
>       `corrplot(M, p.mat = res1$p, sig.level = .2)`

This correlation plot visualizes the correlations between your variables, and the *X*'s are placed on top of non-significant correlations based on your desired threshold, `sig.level`, mapped in the `corrplot` function.

Comment: Never heard the term "(in-)significant correlation" before. In principle, this means whether a correlation is meaningful or not respectively significant. 
In other words: All the entries with the X's cannot be assumed that the correlation is true?

Comment: Quite informal speaking on my part. I should have written ‘non-significant.’ (I suppose I was matching the language in the documentation) I’ll edit. Good catch.